# input text box inline css doesn't work

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm a complete newb to mobile page developement (with html 5 ), so go easy on me.

I have a form layed out in a table with some text inputs.  I'm trying to constrain the width, but no luck.

```
<td colspan='2'>
<input type='text' size='3'/>
</td>
```

This does absolutely nothing to do with the width, but the field still works.

```
<td colspan='2'> 
<input type='text' name='AtoBft' id='AtoBft' style='width: 10px;'/> '
</td>
```

This doesn't only have no effect with the width, but also disables the field (can't type on it).  Note that this page is using jquery-mobile and I've overridden the table styling with this CSS in the head tag (if that matters at all)

```
table, td, th {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Use `data-wrapper-class` as in dupe. Or add `data-role="none"` to input and apply inline styles.

Comment: I did say I'm a newb, right?  I have no idea what dupe is.

Comment: in what way is my question the same as the one you suggested?  That one it talking about borders, my question is about text feild size

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the duplicate? It's about custom styling input in spite of the styles. Have you tried adding `data-role="none"` to input and applying inline styles? http://jsfiddle.net/bnuyrghk/

Comment: OH! I see now.  data-role="none" in the input tag did remove the jquery-mobile styling.  Thank you loads!

Comment: `data-wrapper-class` keeps JQM styles and applies your custom ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you posted works, which means other CSS is changing it.  Setting text to white will make it difficult to see what you're typing, assuming the background is the same color.

Load your page into a browser (on your machine, not a mobile device) and hit F12, then inspect the element.  It will show you what CSS is impacting it, as well as the file and line number of the style.  F12 is your best friend when debugging CSS issues!

Comment: the table text is white, but not the text box.  Actually, I can't even see the cursor in the box when I click it. I can see what I type in the other fields I didn't mess with.

Comment: from the console, I have: " Expected declaration but found '['.  Skipped to next declaration."  and "Error in parsing value for 'pointer-events'.  Declaration dropped." occuring in my page, but with no given line number.  I can't find those things anywhere either

Comment: You don't want to look in the console.  You want to inspect the elements and look at their styles (should be displayed on right side of 'Developer Tools' window).  That will tell you the file and line number from which the style is being applied.